# How to delete a package from AWS CodeArtifact?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact

In AWS documentation is crystal clear how to delete a **package version**, ok.

But, **how can I delete a package**?

I've uploaded a package with a wrong name, I've deleted the only version of it, now I can see a package without any version but I can't find a way to remove the package with the wrong name. :(

Comment: Still waiting on this functionality it seems.  I can't find it in the CLI docs, either.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codeartifact/index.html.  Weird.

Comment: I have the exact same problem now. I guess we're stuck with the empty package…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS added [delete-package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codeartifact/delete-package.html) api in `codeartifact` in the version `1.26.61` (you can delete package in cli, console, APIs)

**AWS Console**

You can select the package and click on `Delete Package` under actions.

[image: delete codeartifact package in aws console]
**CLI:**

You need to update aws-cli to make use of this.

```
aws codeartifact delete-package --domain <domain> --repository <repo> --package "my_package" --format <pypi | maven | npm | nuget>
```

**Boto3**

Update boto3 version to latest

```bash
pip install -U boto3
```

script to delete a package

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client("codeartifact")

response = client.delete_package(
    domain='mydomain',
    repository='myrepo',
    format='npm'|'pypi'|'maven'|'nuget',
    package='mypackage'
)
```